# error when launching eclipse on Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I hava Java 7 installed:

> ➜  ~  java -version
>   java version "1.7.0_76"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_76-b13)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.76-b04, mixed mode)
>   ➜  ~

I downloaded eclipse 4.3 and when launching I receive the error saying it needs :

"To open "Eclipse" you need to install the legacy Java SE 6 runtime".

Do i need to install JavaSE 6 runtime besides having JavaSE 7 runtime??

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to run an older version of Eclipse?

Comment: The Force.com IDE eclipse plugin works with only Eclipse 4.2 or 4.3

Comment: And are you sure you have downloaded the 64bit Eclipse?

Comment: This was an issue with Eclipse 4.3, it doesn't happen with the current 4.5 release.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Yes, I downloaded 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For Mac, and if you don't want to manually mess up with the current installed Java 7 environment, you need to manually download and install a JaveSE 6 runtime

You can find the Apple download at

http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1572

Hope this helps